# Umbraco returning 200 for missing pages

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I have a Umbraco site and have configured the custom error pages for 404 (page not found) and 500 (internal server errors). When I try to access a page which is not existing, I get the custom 404 page. But the HTTP status code returned is 200 rather than 404. Can someone suggest a solution, I am looking for HTTP Status code 404 to be returned.

I have the following mentioned in the Config file

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="errorPages/500.html" mode="RemoteOnly">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="errorPages/404.html" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="errorPages/403.html" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="errorPages/500.html" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="errorPages/503.html" />
</customErrors>
```

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errors/404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errors/403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errors/500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

Thanks

Comment: It works on all my umbraco pages. Can you explain how you have configured your error page? Have you used the config/umbracoSettings.config file? Have you set "CustomErrors" in your Web.config to RemoteOnly?

Comment: I dont understand your message

Comment: Edited my initial question to add the Config content

Comment: Hi, I'd highly recommend using the built-in umbraco error handling instead. http://jondjones.com/learn-umbraco-cms/umbraco-developers-guide/how-to-configure-umbraco/how-to-create-a-404-page-in-umbraco-7

Comment: If that's no option for you, take a look at this: https://forums.asp.net/t/2079017.aspx?200+status+code+returned+for+IIS+404+error+page

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by following instructions on - http://jondjones.com/learn-umbraco-cms/umbraco-developers-guide/how-to-configure-umbraco/how-to-create-a-404-page-in-umbraco-7 . Thanks very much.